# Placeholder content turns red below certain breakpoint - Django CMS

Tags: css, django, django-cms

I have what seems like a bug in a Django CMS website -- below a certain breakpoint (±730) all text content inside placeholder tags turns red. I have commented out all custom CSS stylesheets, removed links to external style sheets and all inline styling to try and pinpoint what is causing it by process of elimination, but no luck. I've stripped the website down to its bare bones but the text is still red. Is there maybe a specific way to style placeholders that I'm not familiar with??

ETA: I've hard refreshed after removing CSS and tried different browsers too. I've also pinned down the line which is responsible for this behaviour - the content placeholder tag underlined here. If the line is there, all the text on the page is red, if it's commented out the text on the rest of the page is normal (but the actual block content is missing). Any ideas why this is happening/how to fix? [click here for the code causing the bahaviour](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0yu4R.jpg)

Comment: Did you clear the cache of the browser, so Ctrl + F5, not just F5?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem yep, hard refresh and tried 2 other browsers too

Comment: I'd look to the browser inspector to see where the colour comes from, rather than the code behind it. There's nothing wrong with the placeholder tag in your screenshot.